# Why is my regex rejecting apostrophes?

Tags: php, regex, apostrophe

I'm making a regex which should match everything like that : `[[First example]]` or `[[I'm an example]]`.

Unfortunately, it doesn't match `[[I'm an example]]` because of the apostrophe.

Here it is :

```
preg_replace_callback('/\[\[([^?"`*%#\\\\:<>]+)\]\]/iU', ...)
```

Simple apostrophes (') are allowed so I really do not understand why it doesn't work.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT : Here is what's happening before I'm using this regex**

```
// This match something [[[like this]]]
$contents = preg_replace_callback('/\[\[\[(.+)\]\]\]/isU',function($matches) {
    return '<blockquote>'.$matches[1].'</blockquote>';
}, $contents);

// This match something [[like that]] but doesn't work with apostrophe/quote when
// the first preg_replace_callback has done his job
$contents = preg_replace_callback('/\[\[([^?"`*%#\\\\:<>]+)\]\]/iU', ..., $contents);
```

Comment: It does work.Try with `preg_match_all`  https://regex101.com/r/oF9hR9/5

Comment: @vks I'm using `preg_replace_callback` (corrected)

Comment: the character beside the `"` in there. is that supposed to be a quote? that's a tick `\`` and not a single quote `'` - two different animals altogether

Comment: Regex isn't the issue, it works as expected. What does the callback do? `$string = '[[I\'m an example]]'; preg_match('/\[\[([^?"\`*%#\\\\:<>]+)\]\]/iU',$string, $matches); print_r($matches);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's a tick, which isn't allowed, as the following characters : ? " * % # \ : < >

Comment: ah ok. So you're checking against what isn't allowed; my mistake.

Comment: @vks  I added some details to my question

Comment: First regex is incorrect. This, `[(.+)\]`, should either be `(.+)` or a list of characters you want/don't want. Second regex should work..

Comment: @chris85 but I want to allow everything in blockquotes..

Comment: Oh, missed that those brackets are escaped. There are too many square brackets in that case. `\[\[\[`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$string = '[[First example]]';
$pattern = '/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/';
preg_match ( $pattern, $string, $matchs );
var_dump ( $matchs );
```

Comment: can we first try and figure out why their code is failing, rather than a drop-in *"try this"*? maybe an added explanation would be nice.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added some details to my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\[\[.*?]]
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qS6tA4/1)**

**Php** code

```
$re = '/\[\[.*?]]/'; 
$str = "not match this but [[Match this example]] and not this"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Btw, if you want to capture the content within brackets you have to use capturing groups:

```
\[\[(.*?)]]
```